# How to compare the login name with name displaying in application for selenium project

Tags: selenium

While Login username given as : `testvalue2016` , after login in application displaying as `Hi, testvalue2016`.

Need to compare `testvalue2016` with `testvalue2016` only.

```
String email = TextProp.getProperty("email");

if(email==xpath of usernamevalue)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should check that the element contains text.

Comment: use `if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("some-xpath")).getText().contains(email))`

Comment: Thanks Sudharsan for Help, It's working fine